# Displaying results of a nested SOQL query in Schema Explorer

Tags: soql, force.com-ide, nested

I have two custom objects, Team (parent) and Player (child). I'm using Schema Explorer in the Force.com IDE to understand the data that exists in those objects. I tried the following simple query as a starting point:

```
SELECT (SELECT Player__c.Email__c from Team__c.Players__r) 
FROM Team__c 
WHERE Name = '14104'
```

The result appears like this:

[image: Results from query]

How do expand these results so that I can actually see the data instead of `Players__r(1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query could be simplified to:

```
SELECT (SELECT Email__c from Players__r) 
  FROM Team__c 
  WHERE Name = '14104'
```

Using Eclipse IDE V30, view the screen shot to see child record values:

[image]

Comment: That's it! I had no idea double clicking would open a new results window. In my experience, whenever I've clicked into a result in Scheme Explorer (like say to try to copy an id), Eclipse freezes up and I have to Force Quit.

Comment: Ironic: when I closed the child records window, Eclipse froze. :(

Comment: hmm -- not for me, I use Eclipse 4.2 (Win 64) and Force.com IDE v 30.  There are alternatives to using Eclipse IDE Schema Explorer - SOQL Explorer (Mac), Developer Console, SFDC Workbench

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are trying to view the columns of the parent object. Why don`t you specify the columns to be retrieved, like this:

SELECT Id, Name,
  (
    SELECT Id, Name
    FROM Players__r
  )
FROM Team__c
  WHERE Name '14104'

This query return a set of Teams, and withing each Team, a query result set of Player fields containing the Player information from the subquery

Comment: No. I'm trying to view Email__c in the child object.